# session slim frmework : configuration?

Tags: php, session, post, token, basic-authentication

i have a problem with my sessions.
i explain :

i have 2 applications :

- a backoffice which manage the differents products and others things of a commerce. (symfony1)
- a drive which allow to stock differents files like pictures of products. (slim framework)

the goal of the mission is when we want update the picture of a product, this picture will be send to the drive.

So, for that, i login the user with that since the backoffice with a post request:

```
$postData = array(
     'login'     => $login,
     'password'  => substr($accountUser->getAcctId(), 0, 5).":".$login
            );
$headers        = "Content-Type: application/json";
$url            = 'http://api.drive.dev/api/v1/users/login';
$response = $this->sendRequestPost($postData, $headers, $url);
```

the response contains a token which allow to be authentificate by the drive.

after, with the token i send the picture to the drive :

```
 if($responseData['token'] != null) {
        //ENVOI DE LA PHOTO
        //envoi de la photo dans apifile
        $authToken = $responseData['token'];
        $path = $_FILES['prod_picture']['tmp_name'];
        $type = $_FILES['prod_picture']['type'];
        $data = file_get_contents($path);
        $base64 = 'data:'.$type.';base64,'.base64_encode($data);
        // The data to send to the API
        $postData = array(
            'jsonData' => json_encode($base64),
            'product'  => preg_replace($patterns, $remplacements,$this->prod->getProdName().".png"),
            'category' => preg_replace($patterns, $remplacements, $this->prod->getCategory()->getCateName()),
            'username' => $login
        );

        $headers       = "Authorization: Basic ".$authToken."\r\n"."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"."Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false\r\n";
        $url           = 'http://api.drive.dev/api/v1/storage/picture';

        $response = $this->sendRequestPost($postData, $headers, $url);
}
```

and on the drive, there is a function which verify if the token received is good :

```
   // on récupère les jetons stocké en session.
    $tokenArray = $this->app->session->get('TOKEN');

    if (is_null($tokenArray))
    {
        $this->app->halt(401, '{"code":401,"message":"session token null"}');
    }
    else
    {
        if (is_array($tokenArray))
        {
            $token = key($tokenArray);
            //si le token correspond l'utilisateur est bien authentifié
            if ($token === $this->token)
                return true;
            else
                $this->app->halt(401, '{"code":401,"message":"Unauthorized", "token_serv":'.$this->token.', "token_app":'.$token.'}');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->app->halt(401, '{"code":401,"message":"Unauthorized", "token_serv": "'.$this->token.'"}');
        }
    }
```

But the token in the session is null whereas it set during the login action :

```
    $user = $model->getUserIdentity($db, $login, hash('ripemd160', $password)); 
    if ($user)
    {
        $user = $user->export();

        // Authentification OK : génération du token
        $token = hash('sha512', base64_encode($login . ':' . $password) . ':' . uniqid());

        $this->app->session->set('TOKEN', array($token => $user['id']));
        $this->app->session->set('user', $user);

        ...

        $tokenJson['user']   = $user;
        $tokenJson['token']  = $token;

        //on envoit l'utilisateur et son token en json.
        echo json_encode($tokenJson);
    }
    else
    {
        //on efface le token en session.
        $this->app->session->remove('TOKEN');
        $this->app->halt(403);
    }
```

it's like if the session is not the same the login's session or it reset.

see the vhost :

```
# api.drive.dev
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/drive/server/web
   ServerName api.drive.dev
</VirtualHost>

# backoffice.xxxx.dev
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "content-type"
   Header set Access-Control-Max-Age 1440

   DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/xxxx/backoffice
   ServerName backoffice.xxxx.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

So, my question is : why? it's a configuration problem or just a error in the code ?

i do the same thing since an other application and it's work, The only difference is that the post request is made ​​in ajax...

thanks in advence for the help and sorry for my worse english if there are faults.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions works based on cookies. (Mostly PHPSESSID cookie) so basically everytime you click a link on browser (or send ajax request) browser automatically sends cookiea to server. Php maps this cookie to your session data and it ia available to your code.

When you make request with php (probably with curl) you need to handle cookies manually to have session.  If your sendrequest method allows cookies you can read cookies from first request and pass them while you are making the second request.

But you already have an authentication with token, if I were you I wouldn't use session and write user data to memcache or redis, and grab user info there by the token provided in the request.

Comment: i retrieve the the phpsessid ('symfony' for me) with session_id in the drive and return it. i set the cookie with setcookie('symfony', $session_id) in sendRequestPost in the backoffice and i send the request but it's don't work...

Comment: @ThibaudLedeux can you post your sendRequestPost method?

Answer (score 0):

here is the function :

```
private function sendRequestPost($postData, $headers, $url, $session_id = null) {

    // Create the context for the request
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => $headers,
            'content' => json_encode($postData),
            'ignore_errors' => true
        )
    ));

    if(!is_null($session_id)){
        setcookie('symfony', $session_id);
    }

    // Send the request
    $response = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, $context);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: actually i know why the session don't find the token in the drive side, it's because it's not the same session when i retrieve the session_id in the login action et the picture action, the session_id are different.